# Python Command Program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to make a program that will run commands. I want to have it so there is a list of commands and the program will take my input command, check to see if its in the list, and then run the command if it does. and if not I want it to print out Invalid Command.

```
    while 1 == 1:
    command = input("Daisy: ")
    commands = ['cmd', 'google']
    if command == 'cmd' or 'google':
        if command == 'cmd':
            os.system("start")
        elif command == 'google':
            webbrowser.open_new('google.ca')
```

this is currently what i have. I already made the list but youll notice in my if statement i want it to check to see if it equals cmd or google. I am going to have a lot more commands then this so in the nature of making things look pretty, i wanted to know if there was a way i could have the command check the list, run the command if its in the list, and if its not, print invalid command.

Comment: ``command == 'cmd' or 'google'`` will not do what you think it does. use ``command in commands`` instead. To answer your question: **yes, there is a way**.

Comment: If your commands become more complicated (take parameters, for example), I would suggest looking at the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function per command, and store the name for command and function to be executed in a dictionary. Like this:

```
def open_google():
    webbrowser.open('google.ca')

commands = {'open_google': open_google}

while True:
    # Get input here
    if command in commands:
        commands[command]()
```

This way you only have to create new functions, and add them to the dictionary. The logic in the main loop remains the same.

Comment: Beat me to typing it out!

Comment: And you probably want to be able to stop the program. So add an if command == 'stop': break to the main loop.

Comment: Thanks Man! This is perfect. I only just started getting into python so please excuse the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most versatile way would be using a dictionary and the exec funktion

```
commands = dict()
commands['google'] = "webbrowser.open_new(\"google.ca\")"
commands['cmd'] = "os.system(\"start\")"

if key in commands:
    exec(commands[key])
```

Can't test this right now but it should work

Comment: The exec function is powerful, but it is a big security risk. I would not recommend using it as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar program, a little console, to help me on the developments.

the solution is a if-elif-else statement because every command is different to the other. So:

```
 while 1 == 1:
    command = input("Daisy: ")
    if command == 'cmd':
        os.system("start")
    elif command == 'google':
        webbrowser.open_new('google.ca')
    elif command == 'new command':
        # put here a new command
    else:
        print('Invalid Command')
```

Array commands and the first if statement aren't necessary because now there is "else" that intercept all invalid commands.

if you want see my code there is a link:  [DevUtils](https://github.com/ffex/DevUtils/blob/master/Linux/LinuxURLManager.py) at line 38 i manage commands.